# How to get the week number, start date and end date of Compelete year in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, week-number

How to get the complete week number, startdate and enddate of complete year.

**Note**

1. Week starts from Sunday to Saturday
2. at the same time week no 1 (ex: 01-01-2020  to  04-01-2020) and last week should be (ex:27-12-2020 to 31-12-2020)

**Expecting result**

```
WeekNo  WeekStartDate   WeekEndDate
===================================
   1    2019-01-01      2019-01-05
   2    2019-01-06      2019-01-12
   3    2019-01-13      2019-01-19
   4    2019-01-20      2019-01-26
   5    2019-01-27      2019-02-02
   6    2019-02-03      2019-02-09
   7    2019-02-10      2019-02-16
   8    2019-02-17      2019-02-23
   9    2019-02-24      2019-03-02
   ...
   ...upto end of the year
```

Actually I tried this one also [rextester](https://rextester.com/KEPB52852)

Comment: What would you consider the final week of this year to be (commencing on 29/12/2019 in you Sunday->Saturday week)? Can your year have 53 weeks?

Comment: @Martin yes you are correct. It can be 53 weeks(ex: week 53= from '29/12/2019' to '31/12/2019')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in *2019 only*, then the following code will produce exactly what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @weekNum INT = 1;

WITH Weeks AS (
    SELECT @weekNum AS WeekNo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT WeekNo + 1 FROM Weeks WHERE WeekNo + 1 <= 53
)
SELECT  WeekNo,
        CASE
          WHEN WeekStartDate < '2019-01-01' THEN CONVERT(DATE, '2019-01-01')
          ELSE CONVERT(DATE, WeekStartDate)
        END AS WeekStartDate,
        CASE
          WHEN WeekEndDate > '2019-12-31' THEN CONVERT(DATE, '2019-12-31')
          ELSE CONVERT(DATE, WeekEndDate)
        END AS WeekEndDate
  FROM  (
        SELECT  WeekNo,
                DATEADD(WEEK, WeekNo - 1, '2018-12-30') AS WeekStartDate,
                DATEADD(WEEK, WeekNo - 1, '2019-01-05') AS WeekEndDate
          FROM  Weeks
        ) a
```

OUTPUT:

```
WeekNo  WeekStartDate   WeekEndDate
1       2019-01-01      2019-01-05
2       2019-01-06      2019-01-12
3       2019-01-13      2019-01-19
4       2019-01-20      2019-01-26
5       2019-01-27      2019-02-02
6       2019-02-03      2019-02-09
7       2019-02-10      2019-02-16
8       2019-02-17      2019-02-23
...
51      2019-12-15      2019-12-21
52      2019-12-22      2019-12-28
53      2019-12-29      2019-12-31
```

**Edit following OP comment about *variable* start and end dates**

Following OP's comment about varying start and end dates, I've revisited the code and made it such that is can work between any two dates:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = CONVERT(DATE, '2019-01-01');
DECLARE @endDate DATE = CONVERT(DATE, '2019-12-31');
DECLARE @weekNum INT = 1;

WITH Weeks AS (
    SELECT @weekNum AS WeekNo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT WeekNo + 1 FROM Weeks WHERE WeekNo + 1 <= DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1
)
SELECT  WeekNo,
        CASE
          WHEN WeekStartDate < @startDate THEN @startDate
          ELSE CONVERT(DATE, WeekStartDate)
        END AS WeekStartDate,
        CASE
          WHEN WeekEndDate > @endDate THEN @endDate
          ELSE CONVERT(DATE, WeekEndDate)
        END AS WeekEndDate
  FROM  (
        SELECT  WeekNo,
                DATEADD(WEEK, WeekNo - 1, OffsetStartDate) AS WeekStartDate,
                DATEADD(WEEK, WeekNo - 1, OffsetEndDate) AS WeekEndDate
          FROM  Weeks
            INNER JOIN  (
                        SELECT  CASE
                                    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) = 1 THEN @startDate
                                    ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate), @startDate)
                                END AS OffsetStartDate,
                                CASE
                                    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate) = 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 6, @startDate)
                                    ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @startDate), @startDate)
                                END AS OffsetEndDate
                        ) a ON 1 = 1
        ) a
```

Simply modify `@startDate` and `@endDate` to reflect the desired start and end dates.  The format of the string is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

This will output a variable number of weeks between the two dates, starting and ending on the specified date (creating partial weeks as needed). Hopefully, as per the requirement.

Comment: you almost correct. But the user parameter is one StartDate and EndDate, So it can be StartDate = 01-01-2017 and EndDate = 31-12-2023 like this

Comment: @Liamneesan Ah I misunderstood the requirement that the start and end dates could be both variable and in different years.  I'll take another look

Comment: @Liamneesan I've updated the answer with a more comprehensive method that works on any date range.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly update on above answer of Martin. You can pass @startDate and @endDate based on your preference.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2019-01-01'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2021-01-01'
DECLARE @totalWeeks BIGINT= NULL

SELECT @totalWeeks =datediff(ww,@startdate,@enddate)

DECLARE @weekNum INT = 1;
WITH Weeks AS (
    SELECT @weekNum AS WeekNo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT WeekNo + 1 FROM Weeks WHERE WeekNo + 1 <= @totalWeeks
)

SELECT  WeekNo,
        CASE
          WHEN WeekStartDate < @startDate THEN CONVERT(DATE, '2019-01-01')
          ELSE CONVERT(DATE, WeekStartDate)
        END AS WeekStartDate,
        CASE
          WHEN WeekEndDate > @endDate THEN CONVERT(DATE, '2019-12-31')
          ELSE CONVERT(DATE, WeekEndDate)
        END AS WeekEndDate
  FROM  (
        SELECT  WeekNo,
                DATEADD(WEEK, WeekNo - 1, @startDate) AS WeekStartDate,
                DATEADD(WEEK, WeekNo - 1, @endDate) AS WeekEndDate
          FROM  Weeks
        ) a
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```